# Does the JIRA REST API have a limitation with number of JIRA ids in the JQL search?

Tags: rest, jira, jira-rest-api

I am running a request against the JIRA REST API and I am getting an error:

```
 Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (Bad Request).
```

I am thinking it has to do with a maximum number of items that can be in the JQL search query.

My query looks something like this:

search?jql=issue+in+('PROJ-741','PROJ-724','PROJ-851','PROJ-854','PROJ-856','PROJ-857','PROJ-980','PROJ-1133','PROJ-1132','PROJ-1071','PROJ-852','PROJ-727','PROJ-725','PROJ-853','PROJ-726','PROJ-434','PROJ-436','PROJ-433','PROJ-734','PROJ-733','PROJ-732','PROJ-182','PROJ-174','PROJ-173','PROJ-133','PROJ-301','PROJ-300','PROJ-281','PROJ-266','PROJ-253','PROJ-293','PROJ-287','PROJ-284','PROJ-276','PROJ-271','PROJ-262','PROJ-248','PROJ-214','PROJ-322','PROJ-323','PROJ-310','PROJ-332','PROJ-399','PROJ-600','PROJ-346','PROJ-389','PROJ-409','PROJ-521','PROJ-505','PROJ-490','PROJ-432','PROJ-486','PROJ-464','PROJ-438','PROJ-566','PROJ-534','PROJ-471','PROJ-178','PROJ-240','PROJ-210','PROJ-205','PROJ-655','PROJ-427','PROJ-419','PROJ-422','PROJ-426','PROJ-441','PROJ-442','PROJ-193','PROJ-194','PROJ-197','PROJ-195','PROJ-196','PROJ-513','PROJ-198','PROJ-514','PROJ-199','PROJ-516','PROJ-515','PROJ-200','PROJ-517','PROJ-201','PROJ-441','PROJ-188','PROJ-190','PROJ-189','PROJ-191','PROJ-192','PROJ-134','PROJ-213','PROJ-217','PROJ-219','PROJ-238','PROJ-237','PROJ-239','PROJ-221','PROJ-330','PROJ-418','PROJ-119','PROJ-463','PROJ-789','PROJ-331','PROJ-837','PROJ-959','PROJ-864','PROJ-957','PROJ-787','PROJ-445','PROJ-476','PROJ-786','PROJ-790','PROJ-791','PROJ-792')&startAt=0&maxResults=900&fields=labels,assignee,components,id,key,created,resolutiondate,customfield_10100,summary,issuetype,status,priority

I could try to batch these up into multiple queries, but I first wanted to see if there was any documented limit (I couldn't find anything mentioned in the documentation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no restriction on the JQL queries and fields has been mentioned within Atlassian Documentation.

But **if the Query is too large to be encoded as a Query Param then you should instead POST to this resource.**

Your JQL has used some *reserved characters* hence it is returning 400 Error.

I have corrected your Query which compiles correctly and returns 200 status. 
Here it is:

```
search?jql=issue%20in%20('PROJ-741'%2C'PROJ-724'%2C'PROJ-851'%2C'PROJ-854'%2C'PROJ-856'%2C'PROJ-857'%2C'PROJ-980'%2C'PROJ-1133'%2C'PROJ-1132'%2C'PROJ-1071'%2C'PROJ-852'%2C'PROJ-727'%2C'PROJ-725'%2C'PROJ-853'%2C'PROJ-726'%2C'PROJ-434'%2C'PROJ-436'%2C'PROJ-433'%2C'PROJ-734'%2C'PROJ-733'%2C'PROJ-732'%2C'PROJ-182'%2C'PROJ-174'%2C'PROJ-173'%2C'PROJ-133'%2C'PROJ-301'%2C'PROJ-300'%2C'PROJ-281'%2C'PROJ-266'%2C'PROJ-253'%2C'PROJ-293'%2C'PROJ-287'%2C'PROJ-284'%2C'PROJ-276'%2C'PROJ-271'%2C'PROJ-262'%2C'PROJ-248'%2C'PROJ-214'%2C'PROJ-322'%2C'PROJ-323'%2C'PROJ-310'%2C'PROJ-332'%2C'PROJ-399'%2C'PROJ-600'%2C'PROJ-346'%2C'PROJ-389'%2C'PROJ-409'%2C'PROJ-521'%2C'PROJ-505'%2C'PROJ-490'%2C'PROJ-432'%2C'PROJ-486'%2C'PROJ-464'%2C'PROJ-438'%2C'PROJ-566'%2C'PROJ-534'%2C'PROJ-471'%2C'PROJ-178'%2C'PROJ-240'%2C'PROJ-210'%2C'PROJ-205'%2C'PROJ-655'%2C'PROJ-427'%2C'PROJ-419'%2C'PROJ-422'%2C'PROJ-426'%2C'PROJ-441'%2C'PROJ-442'%2C'PROJ-193'%2C'PROJ-194'%2C'PROJ-197'%2C'PROJ-195'%2C'PROJ-196'%2C'PROJ-513'%2C'PROJ-198'%2C'PROJ-514'%2C'PROJ-199'%2C'PROJ-516'%2C'PROJ-515'%2C'PROJ-200'%2C'PROJ-517'%2C'PROJ-201'%2C'PROJ-441'%2C'PROJ-188'%2C'PROJ-190'%2C'PROJ-189'%2C'PROJ-191'%2C'PROJ-192'%2C'PROJ-134'%2C'PROJ-213'%2C'PROJ-217'%2C'PROJ-219'%2C'PROJ-238'%2C'PROJ-237'%2C'PROJ-239'%2C'PROJ-221'%2C'PROJ-330'%2C'PROJ-418'%2C'PROJ-119'%2C'PROJ-463'%2C'PROJ-789'%2C'PROJ-331'%2C'PROJ-837'%2C'PROJ-959'%2C'PROJ-864'%2C'PROJ-957'%2C'PROJ-787'%2C'PROJ-445'%2C'PROJ-476'%2C'PROJ-786'%2C'PROJ-790'%2C'PROJ-791'%2C'PROJ-792')&maxResults=900&fields=labels%2Cassignee%2Ccomponents%2Cid%2Ckey%2Ccreated%2Cresolutiondate%2Ccustomfield_10100%2Csummary%2Cissuetype%2Cstatus%2Cpriority
```